# SQL LEFT JOIN help

Tags: sql, mysql, join, innodb

**My scenario:** There are 3 tables for storing tv show information; season, episode and episode_translation.

**My data:** There are 3 seasons, with 3 episodes each one, but there is only translation for one episode.

**My objetive:** I want to get a list of all the seasons and episodes for a show. If there is a translation available in a specified language, show it, otherwise show null.

**My attempt to get serie 1 information in language 1:**

```
    SELECT
     season_number AS season,number AS episode,name
    FROM
     season NATURAL JOIN episode
     NATURAL LEFT JOIN episode_trans
    WHERE
     id_serie=1 AND
     id_lang=1
    ORDER BY
     season_number,number
```

**result:**

```
+--------+---------+--------------------------------+
| season | episode | name                           |
+--------+---------+--------------------------------+
|      3 |       3 | Episode translated into lang 1 | 
+--------+---------+--------------------------------+
```

**expected result**

```
+-----------------+--------------------------------+
| season | episode| name                           |
+-----------------+--------------------------------+
|      1 |      1 | NULL                           |
|      1 |      2 | NULL                           |
|      1 |      3 | NULL                           |
|      2 |      1 | NULL                           |
|      2 |      2 | NULL                           |
|      2 |      3 | NULL                           |
|      3 |      1 | NULL                           |
|      3 |      2 | NULL                           |
|      3 |      3 | Episode translated into lang 1 |
+--------+--------+--------------------------------+
```

**Full DB dump**
http://pastebin.com/Y8yXNHrH

Comment: You're specifying id_lang = 1 in your where clause. If you take that out does it return the expected result?

Comment: **@AllenG**, I'm using MySQL 5.0.90


**@Shaded** If I remove id_lang I get only the episodes which have translation in any language. I don't want episodes wich have translation, I want all episodes always, and only if translation in the specified language is available,  then I want the translation too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to move the id_lang = 1 into the LEFT JOIN clause instead of the WHERE clause. Think of it this way... for all of those rows with no translation the LEFT JOIN gives you back NULLs for all of those translation columns. Then in the WHERE clause you are checking to see if that is equal to 1 - which of course evaluates to FALSE.

It would probably be easier if you included your code in the question next time instead of in a link.

Answer (score 2):

```
LEFT JOIN episode_trans
    ON episode_trans.id_episode = episode.id_episode
    AND episode_trans.id_lang = 1
WHERE id_serie=1
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony,
there is no "episode_trans.number" field, I assume you mean "episode.id_episode". I'll vote your answer as soon as I can (I have no enough reputation to vote yet)

Answer (score 2):

I tested the following on MySQL 4.1 - it returns your expected output:

```
   SELECT s.season_number AS season,
          e.number AS episode,
          et.name
     FROM SEASON s
     JOIN EPISODE e ON e.id_season = s.id_season
LEFT JOIN EPISODE_TRANS et ON et.id_episode = e.id_episode
                          AND et.id_lang = 1
    WHERE s.id_serie = 1
 ORDER BY s.season_number, e.number
```

Generally, when you use ANSI-92 JOIN syntax you need to specify the join criteria in the `ON` clause.  In MySQL, I know that not providing it for INNER JOINs results in a cross join -- a cartesian product.

Comment: Thanks OMG Ponies,
your answer was correct too. I'll vote your answer as soon as I can (I have no enough reputation to vote yet)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
```

instead of

```
NATURAL LEFT JOIN
```

Comment: I've changed "NATURAL LEFT JOIN episode_trans" into "LEFT OUTER JOIN episode_trans USING (id_episode)" but I get the same result

Comment: Check Anthony Faull's answer, he's correct, the where criteria should be in the Join criteria, else there's nothing to fulfill the join.